# jQuery tabs not working properly in Magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magento, magento-1.7

I've been trying to create a set of tabs in Magento using the following plugin:

http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/

After setting it all up, adding the HTML, CSS & javascript the tabs seem to not work correctly instead they sort of act like anchor points on the page.

I've added this to the header of the site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.hashchange.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.easytabs.min.js"></script>
```

And I believe all the files are in the correct place / linked to in the right way.

The jQuery isn't in the above because when I added it to the header there were loads of conflicts as I believe Magento already includes the jQuery library.

Here's an example of the tab so far:

http://bit.ly/1hT1Xa0

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that Magento actually includes Prototype not jQuery.  So make sure you are loading jQuery in no conflict mode.  Also make sure any plugins or dom elements you author use jQuery explicity since $ will be prototype.  It may not be your problem right now but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks @MattPileggi for the reply, I shall bear this in mind for the future of the site. I think I may have run into problems with this before too. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to invoke easytabs by adding

```
$('#tab-container').easytabs();
// try with no conflict if not working
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('#tab-container').easytabs();
```

see more details tab at demo site.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, just to clarify, do you mean add the following under the .js libraries in the head section of the site:

`<script>jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery('#tab-container').easytabs();</script>`

Comment: Yes exactly. Add this below your tabs includes

Comment: This fixed it, you sexy little StsackOverflow('#er');  Thanks for the help!